# I need help to identify a SMD component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I want to identify a SMD component of a Nubia Z9 MAX board (NX512JMB)
In the next picture you can see the red square. A 4 PIN SMD component (or 2 PIN component, I don't know).

The green square I believe that is a resistor (like top component) or a capacitor.

This part of the board is the power connection. The components have broken because of a bad charger.

[image: Nubia Z9 MAX]

On the same board I found a similar component. The next picture show its label. || F1

[image: Other similar component]

I want to see that component (||F1) from the bottom side if it is similar to the missing component layout but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The F1 component is a diode, probably a zener in an SOD962 or SOD882 package. There isn't going to be a good way to find this part without the exact dimensions and the diode voltage.

The red square looks like what is left over from a WLCSP4 or other BGA part, without exact dimensions there is no way to be sure. Without the markings on the part it will be impossible to identify it (Could be [one of these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/circuit-protection/tvs-diodes/144?k=WLCSP4))

[image]

Comment: The red sqare is 1mm x 1mm and the green sqare is 1mm. (it is the smallest smd component, can barely be seen).

Comment: probably less than 1 mm

Comment: I would need the dimensions measured with a caliper to 0.2mm accuracy. It would be nice to know the spacing of the pads on the ripped off part.